# Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) : Installation of Python not found, Python bindings not loaded. R Visualization Power BI

Tags: python, r, error-handling, powerbi, reticulate

I am trying to make interactive visualizations in Power BI. Since Power BI only supports these for R code, I am currently doing my data processing in python using reticulate before making my visualizations in R.

The visualizations in Power BI work fine on Power BI Desktop, but when publishing the reports I receive this error:

```
Loading required package: XML Loading required package: htmlwidgets Please upgrade the 'shiny' package to (at least) version 1.1 Attaching package: 'plotly' The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2': last_plot The following object is masked from 'package:stats': filter The following object is masked from 'package:graphics': layout Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) : Installation of Python not found, Python bindings not loaded.
```

I am not too worried about solving the other errors, but I am unsure if I can access Python on Power BI Services as it appears they may not have Python available where they run R code.